# Enviar valores repetidos al final de un arreglo en JavaScript

Tags: javascript, array

El ejercicio que estoy haciendo pide enviar uno de los valores que se repitan al final del arreglo, para que ningún número se repita.
Ejemplo: si el arreglo es: `[14, 1, 10, 10, 7, 7, 3, 1, 5]` que quede `[14, 1, 10, 7, 3, 1, 5, 10, 7]`

Hasta ahora hice esto y entra en un bucle infinito:

```
function separar(arr) {
  let cambio = true
  while(cambio){
  cambio = false
  for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    if(arr[i] === arr[i+1] || arr[i] === arr[i-1]){
      let aux = arr[i]
      arr.splice(arr[i], 1)
      arr.push(aux)
      cambio = true;
    }
  }
}
return arr;
}    

console.log(separar([14, 1, 10, 10, 7, 7, 3, 1, 5]));
// Resultado: bucle infinito
```

Comment: El ejercicio me parece mal planteado, que pasa en este caso `[1,2,3,3]` o en este otro `[7,7,7,7]`, o en este otro `[7,7,1,2,3,4,7]` y muchos más. Es que enviarlo a último no es un algoritmo valido para que no se repitan consecutivamente.

Comment: Quizas interpretaste mal la consigna del ejercicio, porque como te dijo @Yussef mandarlos al final no te sirve en la mayoria de casos. si los restringis a donde existan como mucho 2 consecutivos iguales mas o menos cuadra, pero en el caso [7,7,1,2,3,4,7] tampoco te funcionaria, porque no esta claro en tu problema que pasa si debo mandar un numero al final cuando ya existe un numero igual alli.

Comment: Me lo había planteado pero el test del ejercicio pide que vayan por último...

Comment: Voto por cerrar esta pregunta porque el ejercicio no tiene solución de la manera en que está planteado

Comment: Quizá para los test del ejercicio, hacerlo así es la respuesta correcta. Puede estar mal planteado, y estoy de acuerdo, pero servir para los casos que va a probar el test.

Answer (score 0):

Una forma sencilla de hacerlo sería creando 2 Array en los cuales ir almacenando los valores, discriminando aquellos que se repiten de los que no se repiten.

Por ejemplo, la siguiente función recorre el Array de entrada y por cada elemento determina si está repetido o no. De acuerdo a esto lo añade a la lista de elementos únicos o a la lista de elementos repetidos.

Al final devuelve la concatenación de ambos Array's.

```js
const array = [14, 1, 10, 10, 7, 7, 3, 1, 5];
const array2 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9];
const array3 = [1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9];

function separar(arr) {
  const unicos = [];
  const repetidos = [];
  for(let value of arr) {
    if(unicos.includes(value)) {
      repetidos.push(value);
    } else {
      unicos.push(value);
    }
  }
  return unicos.concat(repetidos);
}

console.log(separar(array).join(', ')); // 14, 1, 10, 7, 3, 5, 10, 7, 1
console.log(separar(array2).join(', ')); // 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9
console.log(separar(array3).join(', ')); // 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 1, 2
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  min-height: 100%;
  top: 0;
}
```

He utilizado el método [`includes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes), que devuelve `true` si el elemento pasado como argumento es encontrado en el Array, y `false` en caso contrario. Además, para recorrer el Array he utilizado un bucle [`for ... of`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of), aunque se puede usar también [`forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach), o cualquier otra forma de recorrer un Array.

En tu código tienes un bucle `for` anidado dentro de un bucle `while`, y estás modificando el Array "vivo", esto puede producir resultados inesperados, como un bucle infinito.

Espero que esto te ayude a resolver el problema.

Answer (score 0):

Podrías encontrar los repetidos y los no repetidos con [**`indexOf()`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf), luego a estos dos resultados los concatenas, retornando un nuevo array (los elementos que no se repiten van primero y los repetidos van al final), así:

```js
const array1 = [14, 1, 10, 10, 7, 7, 3, 1, 5];
const array2 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9];
const array3 = [1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9];

function separar(arr) {
  noRepetidos = arr.filter((item, index) => arr.indexOf(item) === index);
  repetidos = arr.filter((item, index) => arr.indexOf(item) !== index);

  return noRepetidos.concat(repetidos);
}

console.log(separar(array1).join(", "));
console.log(separar(array2).join(", "));
console.log(separar(array3).join(", "));
```